# While loop wont work in my Linked List

Tags: c++, while-loop, linked-list

my while loop wont work in my linked list, but a for loop will, which I am using a for loop to print the linked list. But I need an integer to place for "n". And i am trying to do that by, by counting the elements in a linked list, which, I need a while loop for. Since when this gets fixed I wont need the for loop in the first place, I just want to try and get it work when counting the elements in a linked list.

```
    int count = 0;
    Hand *crdNode = head;

    while (crdNode != NULL)
    {
       crdNode= crdNode->cardPtr;
       count++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return count;
```

This is all inside a function in a separate source file other than main. Any help would be appreciated.

working loop:

```
    Hand *crdNode = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       cout<< crdNode ->card<<endl;
       crdNode= crdNode->cardPtr;
    }
    cout<<endl;
```

Fill List function

```
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        crdNode = new Hand;
        crdNode ->card = t;
        temp = crdNode;
        head = crdNode;

    }
    else
    {
        crdNode = new Hand;
        crdNode -> card = t;
        crdNode -> cardPtr = head;
        head = crdNode;
        crdNode -> cardPtr = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: How about including the working for loop so we can compare for ourselves?

Comment: will do, thank you.

Comment: Looks like `cardPtr` in your last element is not `NULL`, so the while loop doesn't stop after the last element. When you add a new element to the end of the list make sure that you assign `cardPtr` to `NULL`.

Comment: @Rogus can you look at my fill list function and see where I need to assign it to NULL, Im currently adding them to the front.

Comment: Your inserting function doesn't make sense. When you insert a second element what you're doing is: assign `crdNode->cardPtr = head`, and then you assign `head = crdNode`. If you add a third element you do the same, so `head` starts pointing to the new (third) element. What points to the second element after adding the third element? Try drawing it on a piece of paper or something so you understand what you're doing

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: @Rogus Thank you, I fixed it, I didn't realize.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your "Fill list"

```
if (head == NULL)
{
    crdNode = new Hand;
    crdNode ->card = t;
    crdNode -> cardPtr = NULL;  // Add this line to set the next pointer
    // temp = crdNode;             Remove this line - temp isn't used
    head = crdNode;

}
else
{
    crdNode = new Hand;
    crdNode -> card = t;
    crdNode -> cardPtr = head;
    head = crdNode;
    // crdNode -> cardPtr = NULL;  Remove this line - it destroys the list
}
```

The code can then be rewritten and simplified like:

```
    crdNode = new Hand;
    crdNode -> card = t;
    crdNode -> cardPtr = head;
    head = crdNode;
```

Comment: Read my comment above. Your simplified version does exactly what I described in the comment - this will never have more than two elements and it leads to memory leaks. Each previously added element gets replaced by the new element and nothing points at the previous element!

Comment: @Rogus - You are wrong. This code inserts new element in the front of the list.

Comment: @Rogus - see http://ideone.com/7lQ14O for a running version

Comment: OK my bad, your corrected version (with commenting out the `NULL` assignment) works, analyzed it again. Must've been too early ;) sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Just add one condition in the while loop where you want to insert your 'n'.The while loop goes like this:

```
while(crdNode!=NULL)
{
    if(position==count)
    {
        //insert code
    }
}
```